# How to use COUNT properly with pagination in php?

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

This is how I have my current query setup:

```
SELECT * , (    
SELECT COUNT( * ) 
FROM paintings
WHERE id > 4000
) AS total
FROM paintings
WHERE id > 4000
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Everything works fine if I separate the queries but if I keep it like this the pagination shows 1 id missing at the end of the page.

What would be a better option for selecting count that doesn't return on each row but for the whole?

Ex: this is what I currently get if I pass that in mysql:

```
> +--------+------------+--------+
> |  id    | title      | count  |
> +--------+------------+--------+
> | 2345   | water      |   25   | 
> | 2346   | bread      |   25   | 
> | 2347   | coke       |   25   | 
> | 2348   | beer       |   25   | 
> | 2349   | oranges    |   25   | 
> +--------+------------+--------+
```

Cheers!

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Addition to what genesis posted. Still 2 queries but a little cleaner:

```
# The main query
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM paintings
WHERE id > 4000
LIMIT 0, 30;

# And after get the total
SELECT FOUND_ROWS() AS total;
```

Answer (score 3):

There isn't, in way you did it. Just run 2 queries

```
SELECT 
     *
FROM 
     paintings
WHERE 
     id >4000
LIMIT 
     0 , 30;

SELECT 
    COUNT( * ) as total
FROM 
    paintings
WHERE 
    id >4000
```

Comment: yup, straight forward n simple!

Comment: And if you have them in a stored procedure you only talk to the database once!